# When viewing in mobile view, the drop down list for the menu doesn't works

Tags: wordpress

My wordpress web site have a doubt

1. It used to flow to the section when i click on home |about us | menu | gallery | contact, now it jumps to the section instead of flowing.
2. When viewing in mobile view, the drop down list for the menu doesn't works.

my web url http://www.sarahspancakecafe.com.sg/

Comment: can you show your code and reproduce the mark up that's causing issues in a jsfiddle

Comment: can you explain how to find it?

Comment: how to find what? the mark up? you'd need to add the html that wordpress is rendering and the css that's styling it, add that here and a js fiddle is possible to help people answer your problem

Comment: You have javascript/jquery errors, check the console and fix the errors, then try again.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).on is not a function(anonymous function) @ carousel.js?ver=4.2.2:182(anonymous function) @ carousel.js?ver=4.2.2:205
tab.js?ver=4.2.2:120 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).on is not a function(anonymous function) @ tab.js?ver=4.2.2:120(anonymous function) @ tab.js?ver=4.2.2:125
theme.js?ver=4.2.2:240 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).on is not a function(anonymous function) @ theme.js?ver=4.2.2:240s.extend._Deferred.i.resolveWith @ (index):235i.extend.ready @ (index):235n.addEventListener.L @ (index):235

Comment: // CAROUSEL DATA-API
  // =================

  $(document).on('click.bs.carousel.data-api', '[data-slide], [data-slide-to]', function (e) {
    var $this   = $(this), href
    var $target = $($this.attr('data-target') || (href = $this.attr('href')) && href.replace(/.*(?=#[^\s]+$)/, '')) //strip for ie7
    var options = $.extend({}, $target.data(), $this.data())
    var slideIndex = $this.attr('data-slide-to')
    if (slideIndex) options.interval = false

Comment: You should always put your error messages in the question. Not comment section. @Suranga14

Answer (score 0):

google chrome inspect element say's

Uncaught TypeError: $(...).on is not a function(anonymous function) @ carousel.js?ver=4.2.2:182(anonymous function) @ carousel.js?ver=4.2.2:205

// CAROUSEL DATA-API
  // =================

$(document).on('click.bs.carousel.data-api', '[data-slide], [data-slide-to]', function (e) {
    var $this   = $(this), href
    var $target = $($this.attr('data-target') || (href = $this.attr('href')) && href.replace(/.*(?=#[^\s]+$)/, '')) //strip for ie7
    var options = $.extend({}, $target.data(), $this.data())
    var slideIndex = $this.attr('data-slide-to')
    if (slideIndex) options.interval = false